# Can you render a PHP file into a variable?

Tags: php

If I have a hello.php file like this:

```
Hello, <?php echo $foo; ?>!
```

I would like to do something like this in some php code:

```
$text = renderPhpToString('hello.php', array('foo'=>'World'));
```

and end up with

```
$text == 'Hello, World!'
```

Is this possible with standard PHP 5? Obviously I want more complex templates with loops and so forth..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could use some function like this:

```
function renderPhpToString($file, $vars=null)
{
    if (is_array($vars) && !empty($vars)) {
        extract($vars);
    }
    ob_start();
    include $file;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

It uses the output buffer control function [`ob_start()`](http://docs.php.net/ob_start) to buffer the following output until it’s returned by `ob_get_clean()`.

**Edit**    Make sure that you validate the data passed to this function so that `$vars` doesn’t has a `file` element that would override the passed `$file` argument value.

Comment: better hope someone doesn't send $vars = array('file' => 'http://example.com/hax.php')

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. There is no need to worry about user input in my case. Thanks!

Comment: >>There is no need to worry about user input in my case.

Your not just worried about user input here; a future developer could call the function with $vars = array('file' => 'http://example.com/whoops.php'), and then spend quite a time deubgging this.

Comment: @rmbarnes: That's a little too paranoid. If the future developer is an idiot, then he can spend all the time in the world trying to fix his own mistake. :)

Comment: As another aside - just make <code>$file</code> something innocuous like <code>$bargle</code>, instead of worrying about validating input.

Answer (score 3):

As Gumbo said you have to check for the $file variable, its a subtle bug that has already bitten me. I would use func_get_arg( i ) and have no variables at all, and a minor thing, i would use require.

```
function renderPhpToString( )
{
    if( is_array( func_get_arg(1) ) ) {
        extract( func_get_arg(1) );
    }
    ob_start();
    require func_get_arg( 0 );
    return ob_get_clean();

}
```

Comment: Why not just make `$vars=[]`?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Output-Buffering-With-PHP/

Output buffering might be the place to start.

Answer (score 2):

regarding passing `$vars = array('file' => '/etc/passwd');`, you could use `extract($vars, EXTR_SKIP);`

Comment: IMHO if you think you might need `EXTR_SKIP`, you should consider whether or not there isn't a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php), but might be better of using one of the many template engines.