# how to combine multiple files into one page with jquery or ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, templates

I try to making a template for my project, the important thing is I need to combine few php files became one. but i have problem, when I display it as modal, all looks mess. even some of the functions and scripts didn't working. is there anything that can help or provide the best solution ?... really appreciate for any answers.

This is part of my script...

```
    <div class="section">
<div class="box">
    <div class="title">Test</div>
    <div class="content">

        <div id="load_table"></div>

        // table, add button, edit and delete all is here
        // When i click edit i want show it as modal and i made a template on other files
        // but everithing get mess... any clue to solve my problem ?

        <button id="edit" class="green" type="button"><span>Edit</span></button>
        <script>
            $("#edit").click(function(){
                try {
                    var img_load = "<img src='images/pirobox/loadinfo2.gif' alt='Loading...' />";
                     $("#load_modal").html(img_load).load("template/edit_form_A.php?uid=123");
                     // I put parameter cuz i made some function on that file.
                } catch(e){ alert(e.message); }
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){ 
                // DATATABLE
                // ...
                execute("load_table","template/table_A.php?show=all");

                function execute(action,parameter){
                    if (action!=null) {
                        switch(action) {
                        case "load_table":
                            var img_load = "<img src='images/pirobox/loadinfo2.gif' alt='Loading...' />";
                            $("#load_table").html(img_load).load( parameter );
                            break;
                        case "edit_result": // Callback after modal closed
                            if ( parameter ) {
                                execute("load_table",parameter );
                            }
                            break;
                        default
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you ever used PHP's [include()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function?

Comment: on my separated files ?... i think not. i just put that on my main file. like index.php or header.php. that template is working if i'm not using modal or ajax. I'm confuse... @_@!

Comment: When you say *modal* are you talking about something like a LightBox?

Comment: Remove any `<script>` tags you might have on template/edit_form_A.php and template/table_A.php.

Comment: @cillosis Yes... I'm using pirobox.

Comment: @bfavaretto Yes I'm clean them all and I fix my template. I just need to rebuild my css. now they appear like what I want. but... jquery.validate still not working for that form. there no more'<script>' just 'class=myclass'

Answer (score 0):

[Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/) allows you to use partials in an MVC environment.

Using it will enable you to structure your code more coherently.

You might also want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633494/php-equivalent-for-ror-template-partials-collections) for clarification.

Comment: There are other way without making new ones with CI? ... This is project for my study... and I just have short time to finish it.

Another question... is that possible to load or execute function on files who i call from modal ? like "execute.php?action=test" or just "execute.php" ?