# Load part of page from another file

Tags: php, html

How could i load part of page from another html/php ?

My current situation is :

I have php file which contain :

```
$dirname = dirname(__FILE__); //Path to your *.php file 
$file = $dirname."/enmainheader.php";
$contents = file($file); 
$string = implode($contents);
print_r($string);
```

And my enmainheader.php contain:

```
<image id="logo" src='<?php echo getBaseUrl();?>/images/logo.png'>
```

My problem is : it show php tag as an string does not get my image address.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: common question. You haven't searched for more than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ob_start();

require $file;

$contents = ob_get_clean();
```

This is an often question here. Try use search.
**Example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761922/can-you-render-a-php-file-into-a-variable)**.

---

You were reading a file, but not executing it with:

```
$contents = file($file);
```

So PHP determines script as a simple text file to read.

Suggested approach allows to [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) file to current script and execute it.

[`OB`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)-functions allows to save results in internal memory buffer, instead of outputting it to the client. Between `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` you may output whatever you want, and it will be saved to `$contents`, rather than flushed to the client browser.

Comment: I don't quite get it,it solve my problem but could you describe it more ?

Answer (score 0):

Think it should be;

```
<img id="logo" src="<?php echo getBaseUrl();?>/images/logo.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
include ("enmainheader.php");
```

enmainheader.php

```
<?php function getBaseUrl() { echo "your_path"; } ?>
<image id="logo" src='<?php echo getBaseUrl();?>/images/logo.png'>
```